# expand function, taylors series, combinatorics, generation functions

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

I have to expand $f(z)$ into a formal power series $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ (for $z$ close to 0)

$f(z)= \frac{z^3}{1-4z+3z^2}$

I know that:

$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty z^k$

or:

$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)z^k$

or the general formula:

$\frac{1}{(1-z)^n} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} 2^k$

Anybody know how can I do that for my function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have that $f(z)= \frac{z^3}{1-4z+3z^2} = \frac{z^3}{(1-z)(1-3z)} = - \frac 1 2 z^3 \left(\frac{1}{1-z} - \frac{3} {1-3z} \right)$.

Since $\frac{1}{(1-z)} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ and $\frac{1}{(1-3z)} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k z^k$, you can plug it in and compute the answer.

You get that the coefficient for $z^{k+3}$ is $\frac{3^k-1}{2}$.

Comment: I fixed very minor LaTeX errors. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me how to pass from the fraction to -1/2...?

Answer (score 0):

$\bf hint:$ you can use partial fractions. $$\frac 1{1-4z+3z^2} = \frac A{1-z} + \frac B{ 1 - 3z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + 1 + 3z + 9z^2 + \cdots $$

yoiu find that $A = -\frac 12, B = \frac 32$ so that 
$$\begin{align} \frac 2{1-4z+3z^2} &= \frac  3{ 1 - 3z} - \frac 1{1-z}\\
& = 3\left( 1 + 3z + 9z^2 + \cdots \right) - \left(1+z + z^2 + \cdots \right)\\
&=2 +8z + 26z^2+ \cdots + (3^{n+1} - 1)z^n+\cdots \end{align}$$

therefore $$\frac {2z^3}{1-4z+3z^2} = 2z^3 +8z^4 + 26z^5+ \cdots + (3^{n+4} - 1)z^n+\cdots  $$

Comment: Thanks, I have the suspiction that this is the right form to do the exercice. But can you explain me how to pass form the two franction to the big addition? And what we do with the z^3?